# Did "breaking news" originate from the phrasal verb "break in?"

Tags: phrasal-verbs, language-evolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is news said to be “breaking”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19196/why-is-news-said-to-be-breaking)

Studying phrasal verbs I found ***break in*** meaning as ***interruption***. My teacher suggested that it can be also used in news as ***breaking news***, but usually the midia use the gerund form. Actually, both sounds very similar in speech so I was wondering if ***breaking*** is an evolution of ***break in***.

Answer (score 1):

"Break" itself means interruption, so something that is doing the interrupting is breaking